# Create high resolution jpegs from PDF using sips on OSX

Tags: macos, image-processing, sips

I need the ability to create very high res zoomed jpegs from PDF documents.  I have been able to do it using ghostscript with good results - placed images scale up adequately, fonts render smoothly at the zoomed in resolution.

Unfortunately I have a number of PDFs that ghostscript cannot render accurately so I have been experimenting with sips.

I can get faithfully rendered jpegs out of sips but only at the normal resolution.

However, if I ask sips to zoom in as I do with ghostscript, the fonts looks very pixelated, almost as if rasterizes the PDF first then increases size of the bitmap it has created.

Is there any way to tell sips to zoom first then rasterize as ghostscript appears to be doing?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: No, I resorted to Core Graphics and Python.